# How do I move a clip to a different track in Audacity without changing when it plays?

Tags: audacity

When I move an audio clip to a different track in Audacity dragging and dropping I often accidentally move the clip left or right and unintentionally change the timing for when the clip plays.

How do I move an audio clip to a different track in Audacity without changing when it plays?

[image: moving an audio clip]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   Windows, or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   Mac, **before** you click/hold the header to drag.

This will keep the vertical location.
The red circle demonstrates the click/hold. I can't illustrate the keypress.

[image]